# C#. xlsx date cell import to DataTable by NPOI 2.0

Tags: c#, excel, apache-poi, xlsx, npoi

I'm tried to convert .xlsx file to DataTable format by using NPOI 2.0 library. It's OK, but I have a problem with convert to string date cell. When I try to use construction like row.GetCell(j).ToString() - it's threw exception "Cannot get numeric value from a text cell". I tried to use DateCellValue property, but it also threw this exception. With other cell formats it's work good.
Function, that I use it's:

```
private DataTable xlsxToDT(string fileName)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
        ISheet sheet = workbook.GetSheetAt(0);
        IRow headerRow = sheet.GetRow(0);
        int cellCount = headerRow.LastCellNum;
        for (int i = headerRow.FirstCellNum; i < cellCount; i++)
        {
            DataColumn column = new DataColumn(headerRow.GetCell(i).StringCellValue);
            table.Columns.Add(column);
        }
        int rowCount = sheet.LastRowNum;
        for (int i = (sheet.FirstRowNum); i < sheet.LastRowNum; i++)
        {
            IRow row = sheet.GetRow(i);
            DataRow dataRow = table.NewRow();
            for (int j = row.FirstCellNum; j < cellCount; j++)
            {
                if (row.GetCell(j) != null)
                {
                    //EXCEPTION GENERATING IN THIS CODE
                    dataRow[j] = row.GetCell(j).ToString();
                    ////////////////////////////
                }
            }
            table.Rows.Add(dataRow);
        }
        workbook = null;
        sheet = null;
        return table;
    }
```

UPDATE:
If I insert code like

```
row.GetCell(j).SetCellType(CellType.STRING);
```

in problem cell I have value like "36496.392581018517". Another cells converted correctly

Comment: I tried it with a date cell and no error occured. What's the contents of your cell?

Comment: MD.Unicorn, 02.12.1999  9:25:19. Cell property written that it's date format, but now I see that if I copy and paste cell (not a cell value) - it's paste only "02.12.1999"...

Comment: Nothing seems wrong about it. What is the value of `CellType`?

Comment: MD.Unicorn, CellType is NUMERIC, but NumericCellValue threw "Cannot get a numeric value from a text cell" exception

Comment: If you upload your excel somewhere, I'll take a look at it.

Comment: MD.Unicorn, https://www.dropbox.com/s/r0czjgq0eyq0t75/calls.xlsx

Comment: I ran your code on your file, and the `DataTable` generated successfully! Can you post the exception stack-trace? I think it something realted to the culture settings. Check the value of `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` while running your code.

Comment: MD.Unicorn, CurrentCulture is ru-RU (i'm from Russia). Stack trace - https://www.dropbox.com/s/la9et94wbtrd16v/stack_trace.txt

Comment: Sorry, but it is not the stack-trace of the exception. Debug the project in VisualStudio, when got the exception, click the "View Detail...", expand the exception, and copy the value of "StackTrace". Put it right in your question.

Comment: Bingo! I changed my thread's culture to "ru-RU" and I got the exception :-). I'll come back with an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Second column of your excel file has a date format (`12/2/1999`). This format is not recognized by NPOI in your current culture ("ru-RU"). This seems like a bug in NPOI, becuase when this happens, there is no way to read anything from that cell. The only way I came to, is to change the thread's culture before reading the excel file (and change it back after):

```
private DataTable xlsxToDT(string fileName)
{
    var prevCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    try
    {
        // Put your whole method body here.
    }
    finally
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = prevCulture;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ICell cell = row.GetCell(j);
if (cell != null)
{
    switch (cell.CellType)
    {
        case CellType.String:
            dataRow[j] = cell.StringCellValue;
            break;
        case CellType.Numeric:
            dataRow[j] = cell.NumericCellValue;
            break;
        case CellType.Boolean:
            dataRow[j] = cell.BooleanCellValue;
            break;
        default: dataRow[j] = "ERROR";
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: If it is `Numeric`, better to check if it is a date using `DateUtil.IsCellDateFormatted(cell)`. If yes, `dataRow[j] = cell.DateCellValue;`

Comment: what if `DateUtil.IsCellDateFormatted(cell)` is true, but `cell.DateCellValue` returns `System.NullReferenceException` ?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is create function getValue like this

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"\export.xlsx", FileMode.Open);
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);
ISheet sheet = wb.GetSheetAt(0);
// GetValue here
string text = getValueFromCell(sheet.GetRow(row).GetCell(1));

public string getValueFromCell(ICell cell) {
            string output ="";
            if (cell != null)
            {
                switch (cell.CellType)
                {
                    case CellType.String:
                        output = cell.StringCellValue;
                        break;
                    case CellType.Numeric:
                        //dataRow[j] = cell.NumericCellValue;
                        output = cell.NumericCellValue.ToString();
                        break;
                    case CellType.Boolean:
                        output = cell.BooleanCellValue.ToString();
                        //dataRow[j] = cell.BooleanCellValue;
                        break;
                    default:
                        output = "";
                        break;
                }
            }
            return output;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

This is correct code for xls

```
public DataTable GetDataTableFromExcelFile(string excel_file_Path)
{
    HSSFWorkbook wb;
    NPOI.SS.UserModel.ISheet sh;
    string Sheet_name;

    using (var fs = new FileStream(excel_file_Path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);

        Sheet_name = wb.GetSheetAt(0).SheetName;  //get first sheet name
    }
    DataTable DT = new DataTable();
    DT.Rows.Clear();
    DT.Columns.Clear();

    // get sheet
    sh = wb.GetSheet(Sheet_name);

    // add neccessary columns
    if (DT.Columns.Count < sh.GetRow(0).Cells.Count)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < sh.GetRow(0).Cells.Count; j++)
        {
            DT.Columns.Add(Convert.ToString(sh.GetRow(0).Cells[j]), typeof(string));
        }
    }

    // add row
    DT.Rows.Add();

    int i = 1;
    while (sh.GetRow(i) != null)
    {
        // write row value
        for (int j = 0; j < sh.GetRow(i).Cells.Count; j++)
        {
            var cell = sh.GetRow(i).GetCell(j);

            if (cell != null)
            {
                // TODO: you can add more cell types capatibility, e. g. formula
                switch (cell.CellType)
                {
                    case CellType.Numeric:
                        DT.Rows[i][j] = sh.GetRow(i).GetCell(j).NumericCellValue;
                        //dataGridView1[j, i].Value = sh.GetRow(i).GetCell(j).NumericCellValue;

                        break;
                    case CellType.String:
                        DT.Rows[i-1][j] = sh.GetRow(i).GetCell(j).StringCellValue;

                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        i++;
    }

    return DT;
}
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining what your code does? While it *may* be technically correct, a block of code will help others far more with a block of text explaining what it does, and *why*. BTW, somebody [flagged your answer as a Low Quality Post](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10891310) because [code-only answers are frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/284827).