# Npoi ICell.DateCellValue return NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, datetime-format, npoi

I have this Excel column:

[image]

Formatted as date data format:

[image]

And I get `NullReferenceException` if I try to read the DateTime value.

[image]

Do you know what is wrong here and how to fix it? Is it possible to convert the number into DateTime somehow? For example 31/12/9999 is 2958465 when I change to number format.

**ICell into string extension**

```
public static class NpoiExtension
{
    public static string GetStringValue(this ICell cell)
    {
        switch (cell.CellType)
        {
            case CellType.Numeric:
                if (DateUtil.IsCellDateFormatted(cell)) 
                {
                    try
                    {
                        return cell.DateCellValue.ToString();   
                    }
                    catch (NullReferenceException)
                    {
                        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15040567/c-xlsx-date-cell-import-to-datatable-by-npoi-2-0
                        //var prevCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
                        //CultureInfo customCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB", false);
                        //Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = customCulture;

                        string dateOutput = cell.DateCellValue.ToString();

                        //Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = prevCulture;
                        return dateOutput;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return cell.NumericCellValue.ToString();
                }
            case CellType.String:
                return cell.StringCellValue;

            case CellType.Boolean:
                return cell.BooleanCellValue.ToString();

            default:
                return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and got the date value without error. Is your problem related to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15040567/c-xlsx-date-cell-import-to-datatable-by-npoi-2-0) commented in your code? What culture do you have in `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`?

Comment: By default, I have "en-GB" in `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`. Normally i dont have issues with datetimes, but this column has exception in `DateCellValue`. So the workaround was to use `DateTime.FromOADate()`

Comment: I have "en-GB" too. Maybe related to the NPOI version? Which version do you use? I'm using version 2.4.0.

Comment: I have different version, DotNetCore.NPOI 1.2.1

Comment: Tried successfully with your NPOI version. Still no errors.

Comment: I dont know what can be reason for this error and why it is working in your script.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found solution here [How do I convert an Excel serial date number to a .NET DateTime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727466/how-do-i-convert-an-excel-serial-date-number-to-a-net-datetime) So I add it into my scenario.

```
public static string GetStringValue(this ICell cell)
{
    switch (cell.CellType)
    {
        case CellType.Numeric:
            if (DateUtil.IsCellDateFormatted(cell)) 
            {
                try
                {
                    return cell.DateCellValue.ToString();
                }
                catch (NullReferenceException)
                {
                    return DateTime.FromOADate(cell.NumericCellValue).ToString();
                }
            }
            return cell.NumericCellValue.ToString();

        case CellType.String:
            return cell.StringCellValue;

        case CellType.Boolean:
            return cell.BooleanCellValue.ToString();

        default:
            return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution works like a charm. The odd thing in my scenario was I was having this NullReferenceException sometimes and other times it would run completely normal, crazy stuff. It appears to me, when running for the first time would work normal but when reading for the second time and so on, it would throw the NullReferenceException for no apparently reason. That's why some people say it is normal when in fact we are dealing with some instable behavior that it can't be reproduced at first try.

Comment: @Felipe I also noticed that the NullReferenceException is thrown on the second time I read a file. First read goes through. This is odd. The solution worked for me! For those who wonder how to get a DateTime out of the string:
`var dateValue = DateTime.Parse(cell.GetStringValue()))`

Answer (score 1):

Another neat option to get the DateTime whenever the cell is defined as numeric is getting the cell's numeric value:

`DateTime.FromOADate(cell.NumericCellValue);`

A complete example:

```
        private ICell GetCellValue(string position)
        {
            var cr = new CellReference(position);
            var row = m_Sheet.GetRow(cr.Row);
            return row.GetCell(cr.Col);
        }

        public DateTime? GetCellDateValue(string position)
        {
            ICell cellValue = GetCellValue(position);

            if (cellValue == null)
            {
                // Cell doesn't have any value
                return null;
            }

            if (cellValue.CellType == CellType.Numeric)
            {
                return DateTime.FromOADate(cellValue.NumericCellValue);
            }

            return cellValue.DateCellValue;
        }
```